# serialization in windows forms using restapi

Tags: .net

I am using serialization concept in transforming user information to the database in windows forms using restapi. But I am getting some errors.Can anyone help me plz?

```
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            length = response.ContentLength;
            StreamReader myreader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string mydata = myreader.ReadToEnd();
            var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = myreader.(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            Dictionary<string, string> sData = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
            response.Close();

            string hello = "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx), you should use JSon.Net instead of a JavaScriptSerializer to do your conversion.

Add a nuget reference to Newtonsoft.Json

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Then you can rewrite your code as:

```
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    length = response.ContentLength;
    StreamReader myreader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string mydata = myreader.ReadToEnd();

    var sData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Dictionary<string, MyType>(mydata);

    response.Close();

    string hello = "test";
```

Where **MyType** is the C# class that represents one entry from the JSON that you've downloaded.